# Timer doesn't stop after closing form C#

Tags: c#, timer

i create timer in my form, but after i close form, timer still working.
I tried different ways to stop this timer, but did not have any success.

what is problem?

```
private Timer timer100;

private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.timer100 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
       this.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(this.MainForm_FormClosing);
        this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.MainForm_FormClosed);
    }
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        timer100.Stop();

    }
private void MainForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer100.Dispose();
        timer100 = null;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you start the timer?

Comment: public void NewGame()
        {timer100.Start();}   and newgame used here> public MainForm()
        {NewGame();} >> main form is name of my class.

Comment: Do you also call `InitializeComponent()` in `MainForm`'s constructor as well as `NewGame()`?

Comment: No, i didn't. and i did it now and your answer solved my problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did not put `InitializeComponent()` in `MainForm`'s constructor as [jhmt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5416019/jhmt) mentioned in comments.